# NSJSONSerialization issue - right number of objects, all of them "invalid"

Tags: iphone, json

I'm using NSJSONSerialization (very cool) to decode a string from a server. When I run it through…

```
    id theJSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:inData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
```

I get back an array with 75 objects, exactly what I would expect. However, when I examine any one of those, it tells me:

```
 (<invalid>) [2] = <error: expected ']'
```

So thinking this was a JSON error, I pasted the text into JSONLint, which says it's fine.

I'm new to the JSON stuff, so I'm looking for pointers on how to debug this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a problem with Xcode, the data is correct but the debugger incorrectly interprets it.